# Migrating asp.Net MVC views to angularJS 2 Views/Components

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are in migration phase for product upgrading to the latest technology in client side view rendering. Currently we are having a webapp with asp.net MVC 4(with VS 2012) which we call a middle tier asp.net webapi to access the data. These are two separate projects.

The web app is currently using the MVC Razor view engine for rendering the pages in the front end ,now we are planning to switch all our Razor views to angural2 component and convert all our client side validation/code from existing javascript/jquery  to angular typescrit.

For web api authentication we are using a middleware **OwinKatana implementation** provided by Microsoft (token based authentication and authorization).

Doubts:

```
1.Since angular is preferred for single page application , is it feasible to replace the existing dynamic MVC razor view to angular
component/View .

2.Does angular supports the Owinkatana middleware for web api authentication.

3.Because of anular2 implementation we need to move our development environment from IDE VS 2012 to 2015. VS 2015 offers a very good support to angularJS2 ,typescript,node and npm .Aslo VS 2015 is completely offers a new framework (asp.net core ) does it affect our application built in .net framework 4.5.
```

Please let us know is there any bottleneck with above approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have no coding questions here, however, the following are the general observations

1. When you move from MVC to angular, you will have to replace server controls like grids, `Html.TextBox` etc to plain HTML. Advised to write new directives in Angular for the same
2. You will have to use the existing Web Api, which will work fine with Owin middlewares, but you will be using JWT Bearer or other methods than using both Web App and Api in a single application
3. Upgrading visual studio is an Editor preference and nothing to do with your code.

In case you have any programming issue or a challenge that you need us to help with, please post here.